# Is there a Java library to manipulate Clojure edn data structure?

Tags: java, clojure

I am on a work to dynamically load Clojure functions from strings and parse them. Example:

```
Class.forName(RT.class.getName());
String fnText = "(defn foo [] (println \"foo1\"))";

PersistentList fnObj = (PersistentList) Clojure.read(fnText);
Symbol fnName = (Symbol) fnObj.get(1); // this is stupid
System.out.println(fnName.getName()); // prints "foo"
```

But `fnObj.get(1)` is not convenient. I am wondering is there a xpath like library in Java to manipulate the PersistentList returned from `Clojure.read()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this java library called [edn-java](https://github.com/bpsm/edn-java). Not super active (last commit was Oct 2015).

FWIW, its on the recommended list here:

https://github.com/edn-format/edn/wiki/Implementations